# How to startactivity for result from many activity to the same activity?

Tags: android

i use DrawerLayout to create my project and then my project is allow user to login anytime as they want. so how can i start activity for result from each fragment to the same new activity

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean how to start a activity from fragment?

Comment: You give the same activity class in each method call?

Comment: from fragment you can call directly as getActivity().startActivityForResult(getActivity(), LogInActivity.class)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your question, I assume your `DrawerLayout` is inside an `Activity`, correct?

If that so, the way you are changing fragment is by targetting a `View` inside the `Activity` correct?

Then, just do `getActivity().startActivityForResult(yourIntent, yourRequestCode)`

and in your `Activity`'s `onActivityResult` you can do something like :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode == yourRequestCode) {
// Your code here, you can check the resultCode from here too, and data
// is the intent sent from 
// getActivity().startActivityForResult(yourIntent, yourRequestCode)
}
```

A little addition, you can also `startActivityForResult` from inside a `Fragment` to get result in the `Fragment` too for better understanding and handling depending on your code, simply by removing `getActivity()`

So it'll be like `startActivityForResult(yourIntent, yourRequestCode)`

Comment: You are welcome, and BTW, next time you should be clear about what you need. By how I answered, I assumed the question was something in the line of.. "How can I get activity result of `startActivityForResult` executed inside a Fragment to the `Activity` containing the `Fragments`?"

Comment: i have try this one but the result is make my app crash. i have an activity that manage 4 fragment. and i the fragment i have btnLogin and here is my code: btn_log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Login.class);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,2);*/
                }
            });

Comment: in activity:@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==2){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                log=true;
            }
            else{
                log=false;
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

Comment: I need to know what is the log of the appcrash. Can you please edit your question and put your codes there too along with the AndroidMonitor log?

Comment: Thank u sir for your attention, it run as well right now. and am sorry if i make feel bored or anything, because am just start to use stackoverflow for finding solution, i just learn android for one week also. thank for your help.

Comment: No it's ok man :) I don't feel bored or anything but I kinda care about new developers who are just joining SO, SO users are sometimes harsh on new people who asks unclear question, indifferent whether the question starter is new or not. Trust me, I learnt it the hard way :). And post your own answer when you can, just in case people got the same problem as you did :D